# Does Relations between tables in database speed up performance of queries?

Tags: mysql, database-relations

I am using join in my quires and i want to know if the relations between database tables leads to increase performance of the queries.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For boosting performance, you should use **indexes**, use appropriate datatypes as well (storing number as string takes more space and comparing may be less efficient).

Relations between tables, i.e. foreign key are **constraints**, so you cannot enter new value to referenced table without referencing records in other table - it is a way to keep data integrity, eg.

```
Table1
id  table2_id
1   1
2   1
3   3

Table2
id  some_column
1   123
2   123
3   null
```

Here, `Table1.table2_id` references `Table2.id`. Now you won't be able to insert such row to `Table1`: `4, 4`, because there's no `id = 4` in `Table2`.

Comment: Relations gives you ability to set values to null or even remove whole rows when something related is deleted

Comment: @DamianDziaduch Well, it's not what OP asked, but you're right. This is other topic, what to do when referenced record is deleted: raise error, cascade delete, update referencing row to null :)